# Apply Date format when changing DataType

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm applying Data Type for each `column` in Data Frame like below

```
[StructField('name',StringType(),True), StructField(‘dob’,DateType(),True)]
```

Is there anyway to mention date format `YYYY/MM/DD` in the above statement?

Comment: why should you do? you can use date function like https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#date_format-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-java.lang.String- (for scala) to get string date representation with specific format

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry but no, you can't, and the default Datetype format is this one: **YYYY-MM-DD**, as it says in the [documentation of apache spark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/types/DateType.html):

> A date type, supporting "0001-01-01" through "9999-12-31".